# Let $r_1,$ $r_2,$ $\dots,$ $r_{98}$ be the roots of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{98}x^n=0$. Find $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{98}\frac{r_n^2}{r_n+1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Let $r_1,$ $r_2,$ $\dots,$ $r_{98}$ be the roots of
$$x^{98} + x^{97} + x^{96} + \dots + x^2 + x + 1 = 0.$$Find
$$\frac{r_1^2}{r_1 + 1} + \frac{r_2^2}{r_2 + 1} + \dots + \frac{r_{98}^2}{r_{98} + 1}.$$

---

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with Vieta's formulas, but I'm not really sure how Vieta's can be applied.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, seems like you can start with: $\frac{r^2}{r+1}=r-1+\frac1{r+1}.$

Comment: Hint: The polynomial is palindromic.  The list $(\frac{1}{r_1}, \frac{1}{r_2}, \ldots)$ is a permutation $(r_1, r_2, \ldots )$.

Comment: **LaTeX.** You're [abusing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) `\displaystyle` (especially when editing others' posts). Please stop doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we need to deal with $\frac{1}{r_i+1}$

If $x^{98}+x^{97}+\dots+x+1=0$, we know that

$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{-(x^{98}+x^{97}+\dots+x)}{x+1}=-(x+x^3+\dots+x^{97})$$

Therefore, we have

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{98}\frac{r_n^2}{r_n+1}=-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{98}(r_i^3+r_i^5+\dots+r_i^{99})$$

We can prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{98} r_i^j=-1$ for $j=1,2,\dots,98$ (either by Newton's formula, or times $x-1$ and get $x^{99}-1$, or by the roots of unity). Furthermore, we know that $r_i^{99}=1$. Thus, the desired value is

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{98}\frac{r_n^2}{r_n+1}=-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{98}(r_i^3+r_i^5+\dots+r_i^{99})\\=-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{98}r_i^3-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{98}r_i^5-\dots-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{98}r_i^{99}=1+1+\dots+1-98=48-98=-50$$

Comment: You have $x$'s in many places where you should have $r_n$'s.

Comment: okay, I will fix that

Comment: In the second to last line you still have $x$'s.

Comment: @Gary okay, thanks

Comment: @JetfiRex Could you please explain why $\sum_{i=1}^{98} r_i^j=-1$ for $j=1,2,\dots,98$

Comment: @JetfiRex never mind, I got it. $\sum_{i=1}^{98} r_i^j=\sum_{i=1}^{98} r_j^i=-1$ The first equation is due to $r_i$ is the root of the unity, the second equation is true because $r_i$ is the root of the equation.

Answer (score 5):

As observed by *achille hui*, $r_k^{-1}$ are the roots (in the opposite order), hence $$S=\sum {r_k^2\over r_k+1} =\sum {1\over r_k(r_k+1)}={1\over 2}\left [ \sum {r_k^2\over r_k+1} +\sum {1\over r_k(r_k+1)}\right ]$$
Thus
$$2S=\sum {r_k^3+1\over r_k(r_k+1)}=\sum(r_k-1+r_k^{-1})=2\sum r_k-98$$
Now by Vieta's rule $2S=-2-98=-100$

Answer (score 2):

Just another way, let the desired sum be $S$.  By adding the root $r_0=1$, we get the simpler polynomial $f(x) = x^{99}-1$, and the corresponding sum for this new polynomial is $\frac12+S$.

From $\displaystyle \frac{r_i^2}{r_i+1} = r_i-1 + \frac1{r_i+1}$, we have $\sum r_i = 0$ and $\sum -1 = -99$ (with $\sum$ being the sums over integers $0\leqslant i \leqslant 98$).

What is left is to sum the last term for the roots of $f(x)$.  Using simple transformations, the monic polynomial whose roots are $r_i+1$ is given by $f(x-1)$, and hence a polynomial whose roots are $\frac1{r_i+1}$ is $x^{99}f(\frac1x-1) = (1-x)^{99}-x^{99}$.  So $\sum \frac1{r_i+1} = \frac{99}2$ by Vieta.

Thus $\frac12+S = 0-99+\frac{99}2 \implies S = -50$.